# SharePoint Online list - format group headers to remove column name

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I have a SharePoint Online list that contains employee documents for each of our staff members.

I keep it grouped by employee name which is great, but the word 'Employee:' before each name is really bugging me.

Is there a way to remove the name of the column that appears before the grouping?

For Example:

[image]

Should read as:

[image]

I've seen posts and videos using JSON to format the grouping with background colors, icons, custom text etc. but I can't isolate what's needed to just remove the column name.  I'm super new at all this stuff and just finding my way through things at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below JSON to format list view:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "groupProps": {
    "headerFormatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "padding-left": "12px",
        "font-size": "16px",
        "font-weight": "400",
        "cursor": "pointer",
        "outline": "0px",
        "white-space": "nowrap",
        "text-overflow": "ellipsis"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "span",
              "style": {
                "padding": "5px 5px 5px 5px"
              },
              "txtContent": "@group.fieldData.displayValue"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "div",
              "style": {
                "display": "flex",
                "flex-direction": "row",
                "justify-content": "center"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "txtContent": "=' (' + @group.count + ')'"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**List view without JSON formatting**:

[image]

**List view with JSON formatting**:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Use view formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting)

---

**Update from comments**:

For person or group fields, replace `@group.fieldData.displayValue` with `@group.fieldData.title` in above JSON & it should work for you.

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I copied the JSON exactly and this is what it gave me. [object Object] (16).  So I have removed the Column name, thank you.  But I've also lost the names of the employees.

Comment: Where are you adding this JSON? You have to add it under "format this view" (view formatting) option & not column formatting.

Comment: Yes that's where I put it.  Format Current View > Format View > Advanced Mode.  It takes away the employee names completely.  I don't know if it impacts anything, but I get the employee names from a people picker of current site members, it's not a manual entry into the Title (or similar) column.

Comment: Check updated answer for person or group columns.

Comment: That did it.  Thank you!