# Sharepoint Online - removing the column headings from the group view CODE NOT WORKING NOW

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I've been using the following code successfully and then noticed recently that it's not working. Is this because of an update? Is there any updated code?

Thanks very much.

**Code I used but no longer works**: [SharePoint Online list - remove column name from grouped view](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/299310/sharepoint-online-list-remove-column-name-from-grouped-view)

Comment: What is the data/column type of column used in grouping?

Comment: I just tried the JSON in link you provided for lookup column and it is working fine.

Comment: Make sure lookup column is added to list view, multiple selection is not allowed on column and you are not using multiple levels of grouping in view. Let me know if it works for you after verifying all these settings.