# SharePoint Online list - format group headers to remove column name when multiple columns are grouped

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I have been searching the web to try and find an answer to this question however, all pages seem to relate to just 1 column grouping.

I have a list of people who are grouped together as gangs and then for the company that they work for.

This page [SharePoint Online list - format group headers to remove column name](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/297843/sharepoint-online-list-format-group-headers-to-remove-column-name/297844#297844) accomplishes the sort of view that I am looking for however, when I add the following JSON, the gang does not display:

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "groupProps": {
    "headerFormatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "padding-left": "12px",
        "font-size": "16px",
        "font-weight": "400",
        "cursor": "pointer",
        "outline": "0px",
        "white-space": "nowrap",
        "text-overflow": "ellipsis"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "span",
              "style": {
                "padding": "5px 5px 5px 5px"
              },
              "txtContent": "@group.fieldData.title"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "div",
              "style": {
                "display": "flex",
                "flex-direction": "row",
                "justify-content": "center"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "txtContent": "=' (' + @group.count + ')'"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However, if I leave `@group.fieldData.displayValue` it displays as `[Object] [Object]`.

[image: Display Value]

[image]

What I am looking to achieve is the Company Name in a group without being preceded with "Company Name:" and also the Gang Name in a group without being preceded with "Gang Name:".

Comment: What is the data type of Company Name & Gang Name columns? Both have same data type or different data type?

Comment: They are both look up columns to other Lists. On the other lists, they are single line of texts

Comment: Try using `@group.fieldData.lookupValue` instead of `@group.fieldData.DisplayValue`. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: This works for me partially. I too have two columns grouping. First column is a lookup column (for which this solution works). The second group column in the same list is a calculated column. If I apply the above solution the second column- group header goes blank and only the count shows. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of **lookup columns**, use `@group.fieldData.lookupValue` like given in below JSON:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "debugMode": true,
  "groupProps": {
    "headerFormatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "padding-left": "12px",
        "font-size": "16px",
        "font-weight": "400",
        "cursor": "pointer",
        "outline": "0px",
        "white-space": "nowrap",
        "text-overflow": "ellipsis"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "span",
              "style": {
                "padding": "5px 5px 5px 5px"
              },
              "txtContent": "@group.fieldData.lookupValue"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "div",
              "style": {
                "display": "flex",
                "flex-direction": "row",
                "justify-content": "center"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "txtContent": "=' (' + @group.count + ')'"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**:

**Before applying JSON**:

[image]

**After applying JSON**:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, that has worked perfectly. Thank you

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you.