# How to hide certain fields in sharepoint list

Tags: list

everyone. I have been scouring the internet trying to find the solution here, and everything I'm finding isn't helping. I'm trying to figure out how to hide the 'Q' before the question. That's literally it. I just need the question to display, not the Q: before it. I've tried renaming it, hiding it, but I haven't found a solution yet. I'm using the sharepoint modern.

And while we're at it, if anyone knows how to remove the (1) from at the end of the questions, that would be some swell information to have as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are asking how to hide column names in a grouped view.  This was answered at [SharePoint Online list - format group headers to remove column name](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/297843/sharepoint-online-list-format-group-headers-to-remove-column-name/297844). Use below JSON to format list view:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "groupProps": {
    "headerFormatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "padding-left": "12px",
        "font-size": "16px",
        "font-weight": "400",
        "cursor": "pointer",
        "outline": "0px",
        "white-space": "nowrap",
        "text-overflow": "ellipsis"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "span",
              "style": {
                "padding": "5px 5px 5px 5px"
              },
              "txtContent": "@group.fieldData.displayValue"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "div",
              "style": {
                "display": "flex",
                "flex-direction": "row",
                "justify-content": "center"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "txtContent": "=' (' + @group.count + ')'"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```